# Green's function in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, laplacian, greens-function

I need to solve $\Delta ^{2} u = c $  inside a plane disk of radius a, using the Green's function expansion. The border condition is $u(a,\theta) = 0$.
So I follow the standard procedure of finding the eigenfunctions for the homogeous equation  $\Delta ^{2} u = c $.

And I get:

$u_{n} = r ^ {\lambda_{n}}  (A_{n}\cos(\lambda_{n}\theta)+B_{n}\sin(\lambda_{n}\theta))$

But I can't apply the boundary condition, since it is independent from $\theta$.

Comment: What values can $\lambda_n$ take?

Comment: There are no conditions

Comment: There must be. At least $\lambda_n$ must be integers because of periodic boundary conditions in $\theta$: $u_n(r, 0) = u_n(r, 2\pi).$

Comment: Well, since it is a disk there are periodic boundary conditions in $\theta$

Comment: A clarification: Should it really be $\Delta^2$ (the Laplacian squared), not just $\Delta = \nabla^2$ (the Laplacian)?